# How is this fluent D3 method call possible?

Tags: javascript, api, d3.js

Below are two blocks of JS code.  The second one is simply a copy of the first, but it is broken into two statements.  The blocks are an excerpt of a larger script that draws a D3JS graph.

The first block operates fine, but the second one gives an entirely different result.  How is this possible?  In the second block, the result of the final call on the first statement `.attr("stroke-width", 1.5);`, is assigned to a variable.  The second statement then goes to work on this variable.

This block of code works as expected:

```
const vertexSelection = svg.append("g")
    .attr("stroke", "#fff")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .selectAll("circle")
    .data(vertices)
  .join("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", 'red');
```

This block of code does not work as expected:

```
const vertexSelection = svg.append("g")
    .attr("stroke", "#fff")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5);

vertexSelection
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(vertices)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", 'red');
```

Unfortunately the D3JS API documentation does not consistently describe method return values, which makes this difficult to diagnose.

Comment: Because you have a typo `cricle`?

Comment: Thanks Terry, typo fixed.  I worked out the answer and will post shortly.

Comment: The two snippets have exactly the same output. On top of that, your answer does not apply, because reassigning is not necessary in this case (`data` already returns a new selection). Please post a running code reproducing the behaviour you described (different results).

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I worked it out.  Although the second block of code is going through the same steps as the first, it is not assigning the result to the variable.  Here's a split-block that works.

```
let vertexSelection = svg.append("g")
    .attr("stroke", "#fff")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5);

vertexSelection = vertexSelection.selectAll("circle")
    .data(vertices)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", 'red');
```

Note how the second statement begins with an assignment.